# Building a large solution with multiple dependencies fails unless built manually

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions

I have a faily large solution with 56 projects. Sometimes, when cloning the repo to a new work area and rebuilding from scratch, I get weird problems.

It goes like this:

I load the checked out solution file, and get about 20 stacked dialog-boxes that want me to restore NuGet-libraries. Fine, I do that (but laugh a little about the stacked dialogs)

I do Build-Clean Solution

I do Build-Build Solution

I get 63 Errors of type CS0006 Metadata "MySolution\MyProject\bin\Debug\MyProj.dll" could not be found. About 4-5 DLLs are referenced in these errors.

I then build these "by hand" by right-clicking and doing rebuild, and ultimately I can build the whole project. Obviously, there are some dependency problems, but how can I investigate it since it is supposed to work "automagically"? I would almost prefer to create the build file myself....

Any ideas?

Comment: For each of the `MyProj.dll` not found, click on the project that didn't build and add a reference to `MyProj`, this should set up the proper build order. Assuming they are set to build in your configuration.

Comment: You need to add reference[.dll file] of the other projects to your startup project.

Comment: The reason I get the error is that the projects already are referenced...

Comment: @PeterAndersson those are symptoms, not reasons. That's not such a large solution - I work with solutions that have 100 projects without such issues. *ON THE OTHER HAND* a single reference problem in one project can cascade unexpectedly

Comment: @PeterAndersson for example, are there any projects that reference dlls in their own debug folders, instead of the dependent projects? Did you check the output window for the first error message?

Comment: @PeterAndersson the fact that problems appear when you clone to a new work area is a *strong* indicator that some projects, instead of referencing other projects in the solution, reference the dlls directly

Comment: I'm a C# noob in this case. How do one reference a DLL directly? As far as I can see, only project references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the project (not mine!) was missing Build Dependencies between projects. Apparently I don't fully understand the dependency management (have switched from Java to C# this year), I thought it was more automatic, since I could do "using"-statements without problem I though dependency was setup, but in some cases they were missing. I will investigate this further later on, but for now its is enough that I know that I will have to check each error by itself and verify with the Build settings.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the physical location of project folder -> right click go to properties -> remove or un-check read-only (remove folder read-only) and rebuild solution.

The problem is, sometimes due to, your local copy of solution is read-only and you are trying to build solution (it will try to delete/replace some .exe file during build, but it has restrictions due to read-only mode.)

Nuget package will only restore when physical local package folder not exist or deleted. You can manually delete package folder and build solution, it will first load or install all the dependencies.

try this, may be it will work.

Comment: This looked promising, a lot of folders had write protection. Did GIT do this? Anyway, it made no apparent difference. The fundamental problem was something else.

Comment: Remove read-only from your local copy, it will ask you to apply on sub-folders also, agree and continue. Remove read-only will not effect on actual project this is for your local permissions. Please don't check-in package folder on TFS. I am sure about Visual Studio and TFS and not about GIT.